# Multithreading with pthread little issue

Tags: c++, multithreading, pthreads

I have a function that should iterate through 3 vectors of strings.
The thread function I implemented is something like this:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<pthread.h>
    #include<vector>
    #include<string>
    #include<fstream>
    using namespace std;

    int i_array1=-1,i_array2=0,i_array3=0;
    int total_array1,total_array2,total_array3;
    vector<string> array1;
    vector<string> array2;
    vector<string> array3;
    pthread_mutex_t count;

    void *dostuf(void *threadid) {
        string u,p;
        string i;
        while(1){
                pthread_mutex_lock(&count);

                if(i_array1<total_array1-1){
                    i_array1++;
                    i=array1[i_array1];

                    u=array2[i_array2];

                    p=array3[i_array3];
                }else{
                    i_array1=0;
                    i=array1[0];


                    if(i_array3<total_array3-1){
                        i_array3++;
                        p=array3[i_array3];
                        u=array2[i_array2];

                    }else{
                        i_array3=0;

                        if(i_array2<total_array2-1){
                            i_array2++;

                            p=array3[0];
                            u=array2[i_array2];
                            //cout<<u<<endl;

                        }else{
                            pthread_mutex_unlock(&count);
                            break;

                        }
                    }
                }
                cout<<i_array1<<" "<<i_array2<<" "<<i_array3<<endl;
                pthread_mutex_unlock(&count);


            }       


    }
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
        string x;
        int rc,i;
        pthread_t *threads;
        int num_threads=2;
        pthread_attr_t attr;

        ifstream file1(argv[1]);

        while(getline(file1,x)){
            //cout<<(char*)line.c_str();
            array1.push_back(x);

        }
        file1.close();
        total_array1=array1.size();

        ifstream file2(argv[2]);
        while(getline(file2,x)){
            //cout<<(char*)line.c_str();
            array2.push_back(x);

        }
        file2.close();
        total_array2=array2.size();

        ifstream file3(argv[3]);

        while(getline(file3,x)){
            //cout<<(char*)line.c_str();
            array3.push_back(x);

        }
        file3.close();
        total_array3=array3.size();
        cout<<total_array1<<" "<<total_array2<<" "<<total_array3<<endl<<endl;
        threads=new pthread_t[num_threads];

       pthread_attr_init(&attr);
       pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);
       pthread_mutex_init(&count,PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE);

       for( i = 0; i < num_threads; i++ ) {
         // cout << "main() : creating thread, " << i << endl;
          rc = pthread_create(&threads[i], NULL, dostuf, NULL);

          if (rc) {
             cout << "Error:unable to create thread," << rc << endl;

          }
       }
        for( i = 0; i < num_threads; i++ ) {
          rc = pthread_join(threads[i], NULL);

        }

        cout << "Main: program exiting." << endl;
        pthread_exit(NULL);
        return 0;
        //
    }
`
```

This program should read 3 files from the arguments load the lines into the vectors and display the elements in this order, to keep track i printed just the indexes in stead of the values:

`0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
1 0 0
.....`

For example if i input a file with 1000 lines as the array1, 1 line into array2 and 1 line into array3, the program will display 2000 lines. The problem is when i increase the number of threads from 1 to 2, out of No where 3000 lines are displayed, using the same files as input. With each thread added the number of outputed lines increases by 1000.
I suspect that the i_array2 is not incremented at some  point when threads are rushing, but i used a initialized mutex as I seen in other issues. Or do i miss something simple, i know that the implementation it's a mess.

Thank you!

**EDIT**:
I just found out that the problem is not in the mutex, i tested the program with just a print and a Sleep in between the mutex lock and unlock and seems that threads are waiting for each other. So the problem is something strange with the incrementation of the indexes. I don't get it what is wrong there.

Comment: Why don't you just use `std::thread` and `std::mutex` ?

Answer (score 2):

This code is wrong:

```
   pthread_mutex_init(&count,PTHREAD_PROCESS_PRIVATE);
```

The correct use `pthread_mutex_init()`, per t[he POSIX documentation](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/pthread_mutex_init.html), is

```
 int pthread_mutex_init(pthread_mutex_t *restrict mutex,
       const pthread_mutexattr_t *restrict attr);
```

In your code, that would be

```
pthread_mutex_init(&count,&attr);
```

Enable your compiler warnings and pay attention to them.

Comment: Thanks for the warnings tip. I just found out that the problem is not in the mutex, i tested the program with just a print and a Sleep in between the mutex lock and unlock and seems that threads are waiting for each other. So the problem is something strange with the incrementation of the indexes. I don't get it what is wrong there.